# How to post and retrieve comment card data through Trello API?

Tags: python, api, trello

I'm building a web app that pushes and pulls data to/from Trello using its API.

The current stack is pythonic and I use [py-trello](https://github.com/sarumont/py-trello) to manage most of the API calls.
But there's one endpoint leaving me perplex : [post a comment on a card](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/card#post-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-actions-comments)

It seems like the current [py-trello](https://github.com/sarumont/py-trello) implementation does not provide a way to post a new comment and immediately retrieve its data. For example, you can do it with a List :

```
def add_list(self, name):
    """Add a list to this board
    :name: name for the list
    :return: the list
    :rtype: List
    """
    obj = self.client.fetch_json(
        '/lists',
        http_method='POST',
        post_args={'name': name, 'idBoard': self.id}, )
    return List.from_json(board=self, json_obj=obj)
```

Trello API return the created list object as a JSON object. [py-trello](https://github.com/sarumont/py-trello) turns this JSON into a [List](https://github.com/sarumont/py-trello/blob/master/trello/trellolist.py) object.

Is there a way to do the same with [Card](https://github.com/sarumont/py-trello/blob/master/trello/card.py) comment? Card class comes with an *"add comment"* feature ([code](https://github.com/sarumont/py-trello/blob/master/trello/card.py#L298)).

But Trello seems to return nothing...

```
>>> # Card definition
>>> card = Card(parent=trello_board, card_id=id)
>>> # Fetching card data
>>> card.fetch()
>>> # This is correctly pushed to Trello
>>> obj = card.comment('Foo, bar!')
>>> import pprint
>>> # Hoping to print a big fat JSON
>>> pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
>>> pp.pprint(obj)
None
```

Any clue ? Thanks alot !

Comment: I know this isn't an answer, but  I love your idea of using trello to store and receive data. I have never thought of that. Thanks for bringing this idea.

Comment: Since this is specific to a small library, you might get better answers on the appropriate Github page https://github.com/sarumont/py-trello/issues

Comment: Still, if someone has ever played enough with Trello API... And has the answer... I'm reading

Comment: I'm reading to this seems very useful for my next project!

Comment: any answer on github yet??

Comment: you might find something here [trello python api](https://pythonhosted.org/trello/trello.html)

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes I found the "problem"...which is not a problem. See below.

Comment: @TonyEight thank you where did you download the trello for python?

Comment: You mean the API ? Just did a `pip install py-trello`

Comment: I just started playing with trello and it's a little more difficult then I thought it would be. Is there a module or document with all the commands??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was coming from **py-trello** current implementation. See my answer : https://github.com/sarumont/py-trello/issues/113

Thank you folks !